# Make sed work through 2 or more lines (all lines in this case) instead just one

Tags: ubuntu, text-processing, sed, regular-expression, arguments

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash and I'm ought to enable http2 for a particular website I have on an Nginx environment.

---

Natively, the utility `sed` does its text-processing on the first instance in the first relevant line (using `g` argument would make it to process all instances on the first relevant line), but I desire to do a particular operation on **2 or more lines** (all lines actually).

I took a look at `man sed` and found the `-l` argument that let's you specify number of lines to work with (if I understood correct), but I desire to work on all lines, without being dependent in particular amount of lines.

The particular case I'm having is that I try to unify these two `sed` operations into one:

```
s_a="/etc/nginx/sites-available/"
$domain="example.com"
sed -i "s/listen 443 ssl default_server;/listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;/" $s_a/$domain.conf
sed -i "s/listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;/listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;/" $s_a/$domain.conf
```

I could unify the two `sed` operations to something like:

```
sed -i "s/443 ssl default_server/443 ssl http2 default_server/" $s_a/$domain.conf
```

I assume that the safest way to make sure I cover all relevant lines in such convenient one line operation is to use some argument but I don't know if this can be done with the `-l` argument if at all, or I must use regex.

Comment: What? `sed` processes all lines by default: see the output of `printf "aaa\naa\ncaad\n" | sed 's/aa/bb/'` for example.

Comment: @StephenKitt I think OP is trying to convey that they want to process more than one line at a time..

Comment: @Sundeep he’s just trying to replace all instances of “443 ssl default_server” with “443 ssl http2 default_server”... What difference would processing more than one line at a time make there?

Comment: yeah, on reading question again, I am confused too.. may be just more than one command in single sed command? giving sample input/output would help as usual..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seems to be a mistake here, because:

```
sed -i "s/443 ssl default_server/443 ssl http2 default_server/" $s_a/$domain.conf
```

will work fine; it will replace the first occurrence “443 ssl default_server” with “443 ssl http2 default_server” in all lines of `$s_a/$domain.conf`.

`-l` is only relevant with the `l` command.

`sed` processes all lines unless you tell it not to, for example by quitting early. The `g` option to the `s` command only affects how multiple occurrences of the search term are processed *per line*: without `g`, only the first occurrence is replaced on any given line, whereas with `g`, all occurrences are replaced. In both cases, the replacement is applied to all lines.

Comment: I seem to have confused two situations (you might want to edit an address that): I mistakenly took "natively, `sed` changes only the first occurrence in each line", **as** "natively, `sed` changes only the first occurrence in the first line".